# Logcat doesn't work in android studio

Tags: android

I use android studio 0.4.2 and `logcat` does not work (its just empty). USB debugging is enabled, filters are disabled and log level is verbose. Any ideas?

Comment: In the left pane, have you selected your device (is it even connected through ADB?)

Comment: @Maarten Yes, I have selected my device. I am not sure about ADB connectivity (how can I check it out?). ADB logs are empty too.

Comment: Sometimes when this happens to me, I turn off Android Studio, go to commandline, type `adb devices` to verify that my phone is recognized, and then I restart Android Studio.

Comment: @Maarten it shows that my device is connected.

Comment: @Maarten your suggestion helped me, but I did not shut down Studio instead I used the terminal feature inside of it!

Answer (score 18):

In logcat, try going to the bottom right corner where there is a ">>" and select that. It restarts it.

Comment: This works for me.  Logcat crashes frequently, but this gets it back so you don't have to restart the mega-beast over and over.  Wish they had gotten it out of beta before they bailed on Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the "Debug App" Icon next to the "Run App" Icon or press SHIFT + F9. That seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to developer settings on the phone, and scrolling to the "Monitoring" then "Enable OpenGL Traces" and select LogCat.

Comment: That would only effect a tiny fraction of possible log messages.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything. I unintentionally found that empty tags never show. If you are using empty tags, like me, try filling with some letter (blank spaces didn't work for me).

Answer (score 2):

**On your android monitor:**

1. Restart your LogCat.
2. Set no filters because Android studio 2.2 has Firebase.
3. Clear your searching filter.
4. Select your running device.

If not work clear Android studio caches. **File->invalidate caches/restart**

When apply all way but still not working then use Android device monitor. **Tools -> Android -> Android device monitor.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, restarting Android Studio works for me.

Comment: For me as well. Running Android studio 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Window -> Preferences"

From the left panel, expand "Android" and select "Logcat". Check if "Show logcat view if message priority is atleast:" is equal to "VERBOSE". If needed, select "VERBOSE" and apply.
Now you can see your device events in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it usually takes 20 or more seconds for my logcat to display anything. After it does, I see "debugger waiting to settle" messages. This happens every single time.

Try waiting a while to see if it ends up showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the issue seems to occur frequently while running Android Studio 1.1.0. This often happens after I clear all existing log.

When it does, I tap the restart icon (green curved arrow on top of a grey square) and it start working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it in the device developer options by disabling and enabling Usb debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this thread of solutions,

- Check for if you have multiple devices connected. Than select the device that you want logs from (upper left corner on logcat window). Sometimes, different device is selected rather than one you are debugging your app on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two Android phones plugged in for debugging. Switching phones, using the drop down box, didn't do a thing, so I:

-unplugged both

-restarted Android Studio (and the project)

-plugged in the (one) device for which I wanted to see the logs

That did it for me. Logs were back ... now just to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you make it down here, @Maarten's comment above worked for me. Close Android Studio then `adb devices` at Ubuntu terminal:

`ewan@xxxx:~/AndroidStudioProjects/projectx$ adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
FA7Bxxxxxx2 device`

Restarted Android Studio and logcat window worked again.

UPDATE: d'oh I found that I was inadvertently using version 39 from the terminal window whereas Android Studio was using 41

Answer (score 0):

Clear the log before launch

---

[image: Clear the log before launch]

App -> EditConfigurations -> Miscellaneous -> Clear log before launch